# Trouble parsing through a char array in C

Tags: c, strtok

This is the char array I would like to parse through:

```
array1 word 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

Now I have written the following code to try to do this:

```
    char* variableName = strtok(currentLine, " "); // array1

    strtok(NULL, " "); // skip the 'word' token
    char arrayOfElements[256]; // 256 = maximum line size

    char* currentElement = strtok(NULL, " "); // currentElement = "2,"
    strcpy(arrayOfElements, currentElement); // arrayOfElements = "2,"

    int numberOfArrayElements = 1;

    while (currentElement != NULL ) { // <== I think it's a inifinite loop becuase of this condition but I don't know how to fix this condition
        currentElement = strtok(NULL, " "); // = "3," on first pass
        strcat(arrayOfElements, " "); // = "3, " on first pass
        strcat(arrayOfElements, currentElement); // arrayOfElements = "2, 3," on first pass
        numberOfArrayElements++;
    }
```

My end goal is I want arrayOfElements = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

Comment: What if the second strok() returns NULL? You are happily strcpying a string that might be NULL into arrayOfElements. In fact, you test if it is NULL after the strcpy() or strcat() is done. You should ask first, shoot (access to the string) later.

Comment: Are you trying to just make another string without the leading `"word "` string, or are you trying to create an array of integers from the original string?

Comment: At the end I want arrayOfElements = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reorder your code so the test is made BEFORE any attempt to use the pointer is made. Also, `arrayOfElements` needs to be initialized.

```
char* variableName = strtok(currentLine, " "); // array1

strtok(NULL, " "); // skip the 'word' token
char arrayOfElements[256]; // 256 = maximum line size

char* currentElement = strtok(NULL, " "); // currentElement = "2,"
int numberOfArrayElements = 0;
arrayOfElements[0]='\0';  // initialize the array to an empty string.

while (currentElement != NULL ) {
    if (numberOfArrayElements > 0) 
        strcat(arrayOfElements, " ");
    strcat(arrayOfElements, currentElement);
    numberOfArrayElements++;
    currentElement = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```